# Need the Logs, result values with Start Process of Python file in a robot framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

1. The logs gave out by python file Manikot.py, StartManikot.robot is not printed in the main process. Please help me so that I get all logs from the Manikot.py, StartManikot.robot. The Main file is Verkot.robot

2.StartManikot.robot has variables that I need to use in Verkot.robot. Please help on how to get the same

Note: Here Verkot.robot calls the python file that in turn runs StartManikot.robot

Robot File that calls py process: Verkot.robot

```
Initialize Server
   Start Pre Serializer
   Start Process    Mankiot.py  arg1 arg2
   Log  ${Result_List}
```

File: Manikot.py

```
from robot.api import logger
from robot import run

Class nikot()
    # Function name : run_robot_keyword
    # Functionalities : extract all the Statistics data and returns the dictionary

    def run_robot_keyword(self,user,passwd_key):
        logger.warn("Inside run_robot_keyword")
        Mkot.user = user
        Mkot.passwd_key = passwd_key

        try:
            run('StartManikot.robot',variablefile='Mkot.py')
        except Exception as error:
            logger.warn("run_robot_keyword : Error"+str(error))


if __name__== "__main__":
        utcon = nikot()
        utcon.run_robot_keyword(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

File: StartManikot.robot

```
#This has various Log/ Log To Console statements
#This also has a result, say ${Result_List}
```

Comment: Can you provide some details on what it is you want to achieve with this solution? It seems to me that you want to start Robot Framework from within a Robot Framework test case, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @A.Kootstra : We have done this for parallel processing  `Start Process    Mankiot.py  arg1 arg2` is actually a bunch of independent process that will be initialated by Start Process -Process library. I am adding for loop in above to `Start Process    Mankiot.py  arg1 arg2`